# Why does Composer create-project execution for Laravel fail?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

It appears that unless I use `sudo` my composer command fails to create a Laravel project.

Without `sudo` it gives me the following error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
  copy(/Users/H/.composer/cache/files/laravel/laravel/73094f2633f1b90f3ef  
  6de4a8a5b610532510e0e.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: permission problem. your cache directory is most likly owned by root

Comment: `sudo rm -rf ~/.composer/cache` will clear your composer cache and likely resolve the issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz: yup, that worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you ever execute:

```
sudo composer <anything>
```

Some of your composer home files (`~/.composer/`) will be written by the `root` and if you can't delete or write over them again unless you use `sudo` to become root, so you have 2 options:

1) Change the user of those files back to your own:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R ~/.composer
```

Or on a mac

```
sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~/.composer
```

2) Delete the whole folder (and lose your cache) to restart from scratch:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.composer/cache
```

or even

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.composer
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. I am looking for a while.