# Laravel-5-Generators-Extended

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

I have problem installing this package through Composer:

```
composer require laracasts/generators --dev
```

I get exception:

```
  [ErrorException]
  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied
```

Any idea?

I also tried:

```
composer clear-cache
```

It didn't help.

**Edit:**

```
$ ls -l storage

total 4

drwxrwxrwx+ 1 Sasa i Sandra None 0 May 16 12:36 app  
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 Sasa i Sandra None 0 May 16 12:36 framework  
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 Sasa i Sandra None 0 May 19 12:12 logs
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Composer create-project execution for Laravel fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468438/why-does-composer-create-project-execution-for-laravel-fail)

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate of the question above, but probably related. This is about permissions: change the ownership of the folder your working in and all subfolders. Assuming you're on Linux and working in folder `~/myproject`, do this: `sudo chown -R myusername:myusergroup ~/myproject`.

Comment: As you can see I have permissions for the storage folder.

Comment: Maybe I should change ownership of the folder to my web server (Apache)? @Kryten

Comment: I'm not sure the permissions on the `storage` folder are your problem. composer is going to try to write into the `vendor` folder.

Comment: I tried:  `$ chown -R $USER:www-data vendor`  And I get :
`chown: invalid user: ‘Sasa’`. @Kryten

Comment: Fresh installation of laravel solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a Laravel noob and it took me a few good painstakingly hours to figure this one out. It is my understanding that you'll need to run the installer for your new project with `laravel new <project>` in a directory with write permission. Here's how I've done it:

```
 ### make directory and grant full permissions
 sudo mkdir /var/www/laravel
 sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/
 cd /var/www/laravel/

 ### run laravel installer
 laravel new my-site

 ### move your project in www root
 sudo mv my-site /var/www/
```

Moving the directory to `/var/www/` is optional and you can leave it there or move it to anywhere your need it to be.