# laravel 5.2 multi user authentication from multiple tables using package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

> please suggest any package for multiple user authentication from multiple tables in Laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kbwebs/multiauth` Package. Its easy to install and are well documented. I also use it in one of my project Its works fine.

Here the Link https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth .

If you found any issue installing consult me i will guide you. But i dont think you will need me because its well Documentation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes it is. You can use without any hesitation.

Comment: [ErrorException]                                                             
  copy(/home/tristate/.composer/cache/files/symfony/yaml/cfa86b63eddff36488ba  
  230c5d633d09dd3f8272.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: tell me the procedure you use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125233/discussion-between-manish-and-milan-suthar).

Comment: @MilanSuthar come to chat section

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468438/why-does-composer-create-project-execution-for-laravel-fail.

I dont get any problem installing the above package. I run this command on laravel 5.3 and its working fine. May be you have some other problem related to composer which you need to solve.